# Simulate QWERTY on QWERTZ with script

Tags: autohotkey, keyboard-layout

At my school, the Windows control panel is locked and I am only allow to use the standard German QWERTZ layout there, which I cannot touch-type on. With the agreement of my teacher, I am allowed to use a program or script to simulate the QWERTY layout, which I am used to. This is what I got so far:

```
y::z
z::y
-::Sendraw /
+-::Sendraw ?
+::Sendraw ]
*::SendRaw }
+2::SendRaw @
+3::SendRaw #
+6::Send {^}{Space}
+7::SendRaw &
+8::SendRaw *
+9::SendRaw (
+0::SendRaw )
ß::SendRaw -
+ß::SendRaw _
´::Send {U+003D}
+´::SendRaw +
ö::Send {U+003B}
+ö::SendRaw :
ä::SendRaw '
+ä::SendRaw "
ü::SendRaw [
+ü::SendRaw {
```

Most things work nicely except Shift + 7, 8, 9, 0 and ´

- Shift + 8, 9 or 0 all produce }
- Shift + 7 produces an ^
- Shift + ´ produces an ]
- Minus produces an ^
- Shift + - produces an overflow error.

Fetch pressed keys by unicode is not possible from what I understand.

What am I doing wrong?
Do you maybe know a program which does exactly this, so I can just leave all this?

Comment: It seems the instructions are queued, e.g. you press Shift+8, which is mapped to `*`, which is mapped to `}`. Maybe you shouldn't use `SendRaw` here, as raw key events are interpreted again?

Comment: Do you think the `Send` command will solve it?

Comment: you might wanna try the `$` prefix for hotkeys. not sure if this will solve all of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
y::z
z::y
-::Send {U+002F}        ; /
+-::Send {U+003F}       ; ?
+::Send {U+005D}        ; ]
*::Send {U+007D}        ; }
+2::Send {U+0040}       ; (
+3::Send {U+0023}       ; #
+6::Send {U+005E}{Space}; ^
+7::Send {U+0026}       ; &
+8::Send {U+002A}       ; *
+9::Send {U+0028}       ; (
+0::Send {U+0029}       ; )
ß::Send {U+002D}        ; -
+ß::Send {U+005F}       ; _
´::Send {U+003D}        ; =
+´::Send {U+002B}       ; +
ö::Send {U+003B}        ; ;
+ö::Send {U+003A}       ; :
ä::Send {U+0027}        ; '
+ä::Send {U+0022}       ; " 
ü::Send {U+005B}        ; [
+ü::Send {U+007B}       ; {
^::Send {U+0060}        ; ~
+°::Send {U+007E}       ; `
#::Send {U+005C}        ; \
+'::Send {U+007C}       ; |
```

You just have to use unicode characters as output.